# Texts on Aghori Keenaram

Tags: tantra

One often encounters the name of *Aghori Keenaram* while studying the history of *Vama Marga*.

- Who exactly was **Aghori Keenaram** and what are his contributions to the *Aghori* sect?
- Are there any biographical texts which detail his contributions and accomplishments?
- Has he authored any text(s) which survive today?